# How to pass line breaks through jQ.append()?

Tags: jquery, html, append, line-breaks

Using some simple jQ logic from http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2011/12/simple-jquery-tooltip/ to create a simple tool tip like effect.

However when I add a line break in the JQ code everything goes south and the logic stops working (FF).

Works:

```
$(this).append('<div class="tooltip"><p>This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.</p></div>');
```

Does Not:

```
$(this).append('
<div class="tooltip"><p>This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.</p></div>
');
```

Checking the jQ docs it states nothing I could find about this being an issue.

Anyone know why it breaks and / or how I pass line breaks to jQ.append()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside the append you have to skip the line breaks with backslash.

in your case:

```js
$(this).append('\
<div class="tooltip"><p>This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.</p></div>\
');
```